# How can I delete registry keys in Inno Setup on uninstallation?

Tags: registry, inno-setup

I add registry keys from the .reg file like this:

```
[Files]
Source: "{#SourceProject}\REG\CliReg.reg"; DestDir: "{app}"; Components: execfiles
```

Then I run the .reg file:

```
procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
var
  Code: Integer;
begin
  if CurStep = ssPostInstall  then
    begin
      Exec('C:\Windows\SysWOW64\reg.exe', 'import ' + ExpandConstant('{app}') + '\CliReg.reg', '', SW_HIDE, ewWaitUntilTerminated, Code);
      DeleteFile(ExpandConstant('{app}') + '\CliReg.reg');
    end;
end;
```

I need to delete all the keys when I uninstall the program.
I made a copy of my .reg file, changed it by adding the '-' sign before all the keys and then ran this:

```
procedure CurUninstallStepChanged(CurUninstallStep: TUninstallStep);
var
  Code: Integer;
begin
  if CurUninstallStep = usPostUninstall then
    begin
      Exec('C:\Windows\SysWOW64\reg.exe', 'import {#SourceProject}\REG\UnCliReg.reg', '', SW_HIDE, ewWaitUntilTerminated, Code);  
    end; 
end;
```

The result is actually not was I was expecting. Two upper level empty folders were not deleted.
Is there any other way to do this so I won't even need a copy of my .reg file?

Here's my .reg file to delete the keys:

```
REGEDIT4

[-HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ABSystem\Office4\Client]
"AutoConnect"=dword:00000001
"BitmapFileName"="graphres\\Parchmtd.bmp"
"TitleBitmapFileName"="graphres\\Parchmtl.bmp"
"UseBackBitmap"=dword:00000001
"LastConnectConfigID"="trial"
"LastConnectDBID"="default"
"LastConnectTo"=""
"IfOneThenConnect"=dword:00000001
"ShowCaptionsInSysMenu"=dword:00000001
"UseIEToShowInfo"=dword:00000000
"SourceColor"=dword:00000000
"TargetColor"=dword:00000000
"TitleSourceColor"=dword:00000000
"TitleTargetColor"=dword:00000000
"UseGradient"=dword:00000000
"UseTitleGradient"=dword:00000000
"OLHotKeys"=dword:00008041
"AutoShowLOBar"=dword:00000000
"UseScrollLOBar"=dword:00000000
"ModeFontColor"=dword:00000000
"ModeShadowColor"=dword:00ffffff
"MsgServOnTop"=dword:00000001
"EEC"=dword:00000000
"EDE"=dword:00000001
"ActiveX"=dword:00000000
"SkipDsgnHandleTicks"=dword:0000003c
"StopCompileIfError"=dword:00000001
"ShowLogMode"=dword:00000000
"AnimsteQuery"=dword:00000000
"OnAutoFilter"=dword:00000000
"EdDTS"="1.1.0"
"EdDTE"="1.1.0"
"DataPeriod"=dword:ffffffff
"DoPlayIncMessage"=dword:00000001
"PlayOnSpeaker"=dword:00000001
"WavFilePath"=""
"SpeakerFreq"=dword:000001f4
"Autologin"=dword:00000000
"AutologinPwd"=hex:00,00

[-HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ABSystem\Office4\Client\Designer]
"GridSizeX"=dword:00000004
"GridSizeY"=dword:00000004
"DesignerUseGrid"=dword:00000001
"CompileBeforeSave"=dword:00000001
"CompileHidden"=dword:00000001
"ToolsDockW"=dword:000003a8
"ToolsDockH"=dword:00000038
"ToolsNoDockW"=dword:00000268
"ToolsNoDockH"=dword:00000050
"ToolsDockSite"="TDockPanel"
"ToolsLeft"=dword:0000000c
"ToolsTop"=dword:00000000
"ToolsHided"=dword:00000001
"InspectDockW"=dword:000000b4
"InspectDockH"=dword:00000249
"InspectNoDockW"=dword:000000bc
"InspectNoDockH"=dword:00000261
"InspectDockSite"="LDockPanel"
"InspectLeft"=dword:00000000
"InspectTop"=dword:0000000c
"InspectHided"=dword:00000001
"MessagesDockW"=dword:000003a8
"MessagesHided"=dword:00000000
"MessagesDockH"=dword:0000002b
"MessagesNoDockW"=dword:000003b0
"MessagesNoDockH"=dword:00000043
"MessagesDockSite"="BDockPanel"
"MessagesLeft"=dword:0000000c
"MessagesTop"=dword:0000000c
"ShowAsmText"=dword:00000000

[-HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ABSystem\Office4\Client\Designer\Components]

[-HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ABSystem\Office4\Client\Designer\Components\{22C87BED-0968-11D4-895A-00A0C9DC0CC3}]

[-HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ABSystem\Office4\Client\Designer\Components\{22C87C04-0968-11D4-895A-00A0C9DC0CC3}]

[-HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ABSystem\Office4\Client\Designer\Components\{335F04EF-6DF4-11D4-895C-0090272D5A2F}]

[-HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ABSystem\Office4\Client\Designer\Components\{5C6E8F61-9DB4-11D3-9B43-0090272D5A2F}]

[-HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ABSystem\Office4\Client\Designer\Components\{75FD9C66-75BD-11D3-9B43-0090272D5A2F}]

[-HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ABSystem\Office4\Client\Designer\Components\{89DCC525-6172-11D4-895C-0090272D5A2F}]

[-HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ABSystem\Office4\Client\Designer\Components\{89DCC52B-6172-11D4-895C-0090272D5A2F}]

[-HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ABSystem\Office4\Client\Designer\Components\{8D3B7C03-C9A0-11D3-B378-0090278D41A1}]

[-HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ABSystem\Office4\Client\Designer\Components\{9169B47B-C8D2-11D3-B377-0090278D41A1}]

[-HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ABSystem\Office4\Client\Designer\Components\{E6038DDD-A12B-463B-8D6A-5D8F4A6B2828}]

[-HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ABSystem\Office4\Client\Designer\Components\{E7DB0A0D-9160-4E86-8D80-23F1C5BBDDBA}]

[-HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ABSystem\Office4\Client\OptionsClasses]
"OptionClass1"="{ACF85B87-9384-11D3-9B43-0090272D5A2F}"

[-HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ABSystem\Office4\Client\Designer\TextEditor]
"ShowUnitFullName"=dword:00000000
"EasyCoderHeight"=dword:000000fa
"EasyCoderWidth"=dword:000000fa

[-HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ABSystem\Office4\Client\Designer\TextEditor\DisplayOptions]
"FontName"="Courier New"
"FontSize"=dword:0000000a
"LinesInterval"=dword:00000000
"VisibleGutter"=dword:00000001
"GutterWidth"=dword:00000019
"VisibleRightMargin"=dword:00000001
"RightMargin"=dword:00000050
"BriefCursorShapes"=dword:00000000
"HintReshowDelay"=dword:00000175   

[-HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\ABSystem\Office4\Client\Designer\TextEditor\FindReplace]
"FindOptions"=dword:00000000
"FindOrigin"=dword:00000000
"FindStrings"=""
"ReplaceStrings"=""      

[-HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\ABSystem\Office4\Client\Designer\TextEditor\EditorOptions]
"AutoIndentMode"=dword:00000001
"BackspaceUnindents"=dword:00000001
"DoubleClickLine"=dword:00000000
"FindTextAtCursor"=dword:00000001
"GroupUndo"=dword:00000001
"KeepTrailingBlanks"=dword:00000000
"OverwriteBlocks"=dword:00000001
"PersistentBlocks"=dword:00000000
"SmartTab"=dword:00000001
"TabStop"=dword:00000008
"UndoAfterSave"=dword:00000001
"UseSyntaxHighlight"=dword:00000001
```

Here's the result:
[image]
I want to delete everything that's been installed though.
The [Registry] section is not actually what I need, because I have .reg files to read from and that's more convenient for me.

Comment: See the Inno Setup documentation, in the *Setup Script Sections* topic, specifically the *[Registry] section* subtopic. It shows how to have the installer both create the registry entries at the time of installation and to have the uninstaller remove them when executed.

Comment: What @Ken wrote. Or if you want to fix your .reg file, we obviously need to see it.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I've edited my question so you can see the .reg file.

Comment: I've meant your .reg file for deleting the keys.

Comment: It's exactly the same, only that it has the '-' character before each key in square brackets. I've changed it.

Comment: *Is there any other way to do this so I won't even need a copy of my .reg file?* The [Resitry] section is how you would do that, and how you can easily handle the removal.

Comment: @KenWhite But then I won't be able to use my .reg files and will have to add all those lines to my .iss script file.

Comment: How do *so I won't even need a reg file* and *I won't be able to use my .reg files* make any sense  together? *How can I have my cake and eat it too?*. You aked a question about removing the registry entries completely using InnoSetup, but don't want an answer to the very question you've asked. Can you maybe make up your mind and edit your quesiton to ask what you really want to know? You're writing conflicting information in the comments.

Comment: @KenWhite I have my .reg file. To do the job I have to create another .reg file and still not all the folders get deleted. That's what I meant when I said _so I won't even need a reg file_. My question is: Can I somehow do this with only one .reg file?

Comment: How would you possibly add and then delete the same registry keys in the same .reg file? It would add the entries and then immediately delete them again.

Comment: Keep your `.reg` file for adding the keys and values. And use `[Registry]` for removing the root key. It's one line. Or maybe two more to remove the parent keys if they are empty.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Also, because I use the 64-bit OS, my keys are not in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\, but in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\ instead. Can this be the reason why my other .reg file did not delete the upper level folders?

Comment: No that is not related. If you want to delete the parent keys, you have to explicitly ask for that in the .reg file. And that's not safe, as they can contain other subkeys. While in `[Registry]` you can handle that safely.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Do I have to specify the WOW6432Node in the path while deleting my keys? I didn't do that while adding. The system automatically put them in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write your own function in the `[Code]`-section. Read your *.reg-file (with `LoadStringsFromFile`) and parse the strings for the created keys.

Call this function in `CurUninstallStepChanged` with `if ( CurUninstallStep = usPostUninstall )`.

In the function you can use `RegKeyExists` to check whether a key is removed or not. If not then remove it with `RegDeleteKeyIncludingSubkeys`or `RegDeleteKeyIfEmpty`.

Comment: I believe it's bit an overkill, but it can work. Deleting the root registry key using a simple `[Registry]` entry would suffice for OP's purpose.

Comment: As I understand the question the keys in question are in its own file. The keys have to be extracted from this file. If they would be known "inside" the iss-file then you would be right and the procedure described above would be obsolete.